# How do I modify PAM's configuration on Ubuntu 15.10 so as to remove the password restrictions?

Tags: login, password

My main account on my Ubuntu 15.10 has a password that does NOT meet the system's default password requirements. It is this way because either:

- setting the password on installation doesn't run into any restrictions.
- it was set during an earlier version which did not have such restrictions.

I have created a test user through the GUI and I am trying to set the password to `test`. It will not accept it. Other answers on this site say that I need to change the twenty-fifth line in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` from

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

to

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so minlen=1 sha512
```

I did that, but the GUI still will not let me set my test user's password to `test`. Please tell me how to remove these password restrictions.

Comment: Did you try changing the password on the command line? (I hope the GUI doesn't set its own restrictions, but…)